# Determining if digits in an integer are odd or even

Tags: c++

In a c++ program, how would you determine if the digits in an integer that was inputted by the user were even or odd. The idea being that a user inputs a 3 to 9 digit integer and the program decides if all the digits in the integer are all even or all odd. Please help I'm completely lost

Comment: Too elementary. I am sure this question may be a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Take a look into the Modulo operator (%). You can use that to modulo a number by 2. If it is 0 (i.e. no remainder) then you know it's positive. If it's anything else (i.e. 1) then you know it had a remainder and was therefore not evenly divisible by 2 and therefore is odd.

If you want to do this on a per-digit basis then you need a way to also iterate through all the digits. You can do some loops with clever math to isolate each digit using the fact that each digit is a base-10. Another idea would be to convert it to a string and then loop over it character by character.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting from your question is that you take an integer(length 3-9) and have to tell whether all digits of the number is odd or even so, for it

```
int odd = 0, even = 0, num, temp;
cin>>num;
while(num>0){
   temp = num%10;
   if(temp&1) odd++;
   else even++;
   num /= 10;
}

if(even && !odd) cout<<"All even";
else if(odd && !even) cout<<"All Odd";
else cout<<"Mixed";
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: The line "else even++"  should be "else even++;"  (It means the semi-colon is currently missing at the end of the line)